# Unable to read in shapefile using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to read in a shapefile:

```
sph = gpd.read_file("taxi_zones.shp", encoding="utf-8")
```

but I am getting this error:

```
'taxi_zones.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Not entirely sure what this means.

Comment: How are you defining your workspace? What happens if you hard code in the shapefile path? Are you able to read in other shapefiles?

Comment: @Aaron hello! Unfortunately I only have that one shape file. I found that I was able to use the shapefile library to read in my file but I’m not sure how similar or different it is to reading it in geopandas (as the latter creates a data frame I believe). While reading it in from the shapefile library I got this error ‘Reader’ object is not subcriptable. I’m not sure how the shapefile library stores it so I’m quite confused atm.

Comment: Does the same file work in QGIS?

Comment: `sph = gpd.read_file(r"C:\full\path\to\taxi_zones.shp")`

Comment: @bugmenot123 Hi, unfortunately not. I tried it on fiona as well. I am not sure what is wrong. Im running this on my uni's VM. Oddly it works on my own laptops server. But my files are a bit too large to be working on my own machine.

Comment: @BERA Hello i would like to try that but I am working on a VM and I'm not sure what to my full path tho I have just saved it on the main page on my jupyter along side my notebook.

Comment: Try opening a terminal, locating your shape file directory, and run the `pwd` command. This will print your working directory. Use that in your file path.

Comment: Did you copy all necessary files or just the single .shp file? Shapefile is an ancient and weird format that is actually made up of several files with the same basename.

Comment: @Aaron Hello again, as instructed i got my file path using pwd and tried calling in the via the full path. the output is still "...shp' not recognized as a supported file format. I am going bonkers atm tho thank you for your kind replies.

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes i have all of the files that was in the file but i don't know why it is saying that the file is not supported hmm... neither can i find what that even means sigh

Comment: You can certainly find other shapefiles from the web for testing and I recommend to do that. If you can open another shapefile you know that your code is OK and you can concentrate on fixing the taxi_zone.shp. It is a good sign that it works on some machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, your shapefile is corrupted based on the information I gathered in the comments--primarily, that you cannot open the file in QGIS. Here are the troubleshooting steps that I use to address an error such as yours:

1. Double check the file path
2. Try to open a different file in the same command
3. See if the shapefile is corrupted by opening it in QGIS/ArcGIS
4. If corrupted, try to acquire a fresh copy from the source

Answer (score 0):

As a user previously mentioned, I believe that the initial file I downloaded was indeed corrupt.

The new way I downloaded was:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/misc/taxi_zones.zip", "taxi_zones.zip")
with zipfile.ZipFile("taxi_zones.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("./shape")

sf = gpd.read_file(r"../shape/taxi_zones.shp")
```

Loads and works fine!

Comment: So Aaron was correct. Please accept and upvote his anwer.